# How to delete blank characters before word in the cell for the column -VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So currently in column B, there are cells that have no spaces before them but there are also cells that do.

For example: cell B1 would just be "Market:" but then cell B4, B5,B6,B10, B14, etc would have "_____Total:" ( __ meaning blank space)

What would I have to write to delete the 5 spaces before "Total:"?

I currently have:

```
    mos = Range("B:B")

    For Each x In mos
        xv = x.Value
        If Left(xv, 1) = "" Then xv = Right(xv, Len(xv) - 1)

    Next xv
```

which gives me an error.

Please let me know what I should do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `Trim$` function. `Trim` function removes excess trailing and leading white space. `Trim$` is a typed function and is faster.
2. Using `Intersect`, as below, means only processing the necessary number of rows and not the entire column B.
3. Be explicit. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code to force variable declaration and declare your variables. And fully qualify which sheet you are working with.
4. As noted in another answer, there are variants such as `LTrim$` just to remove from left (Start of string) and `RTrim$`, just to remove from right (end of string).

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()

    Dim mos As Range
    Dim x As Range

    With ActiveSheet                             'change to appropriate worksheetname

        Set mos = .Range("B:B")

        For Each x In Intersect(mos, .UsedRange)
            x = Trim$(x)
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

Bonus:

There are a lot of existing functions written to "clean" strings removing all "extra" white space characters i.e. leaving only single internal white spaces.

Here is one by [Henry Habermacher](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2f3f9a60-4da6-40a2-828a-8c9b58586119/is-there-a-way-to-remove-all-extra-spaces-in-a-string?forum=accessdev)

```
Public Function removeObsoleteWhiteSpace _
  (FromString As Variant) As Variant
  If IsNull(FromString) Then 'handle Null values
    removeObsoleteWhiteSpace = Null
    Exit Function
  End If
  Dim strTemp As String
  strTemp = Replace(FromString, vbCr, " ")
  strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbLf, " ")
  strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbTab, " ")
  strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbVerticalTab, " ")
  strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbBack, " ")
  strTemp = Replace(strTemp, vbNullChar, " ")
  While InStr(strTemp, "  ") > 0
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, "  ", " ")
  Wend
  strTemp = Trim(strTemp)
  removeObsoleteWhiteSpace = strTemp
End Function
```

Example call:

```
Public Sub testing()

    Debug.Print removeObsoleteWhiteSpace("  my string    with a few      spaces    ")

End Sub
```

Comment: You could further reduce mos into the actual loop range and avoid setting it as a variable but I will leave it there on the assumption you might want to do something with it......    For Each x In Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid looping you can use:

```
Dim myAddress As String
myAddress = "B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range(myAddress) = Evaluate("IF(" & myAddress & "="""","""",TRIM(" & myAddress & "))")
```

which can be also written as:

```
With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    .Value = Evaluate("IF(" & .Address & "="""","""",TRIM(" & .Address & "))")
End With
```

or `Replace()` method:

```
Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Replace what:=" ", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
```

---

of course all above solutions assume that you only have extra *spaces* at the beginning of each cell content, or they will *trim* (first two solutions) or eliminate (3rd solution) other *spaces* also

if you actually have the need to eliminate the leading spaces (the ones preceding the first not blank character) leaving all other ones in place, then you have to loop and use `LTrim()` VBA function:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    cell.Value = LTrim(cell.Value)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, didn't realize your loop was only to remove spaces.

This is how I trim my spaces:

```
Sub trim()
Dim mos As Range

    Set mos = Range("B:B")
    mos.Value = Application.trim(mos)

End Sub
```